# How to connect to Mssql container from my local machine?

Tags: sql-server, docker

Created a mssql docker container using:

```
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=pass' -p 1433:1433
 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
```

Then I want to access this from my command line using sqlcmd. I use the following:

```
sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 -U sa -P pass
```

But the response is:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server: Login timeout expired. 
>       Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Timeout error [258]. . 
>       Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server: Unable to complete login process due to delay in prelogin response.

However, I have tried executing the same inside the docker container and it works:

```
docker exec -it <container_id> bash

root@91207818fbf0:/# /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P
```

This works as expected. Do I have to increase memory or timeout in MSSql?

Comment: just a guess, is a TPC protocol enabled in SQL Server configuration?

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev: let  me check that

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev: Do you know any direct way of checking it from command line.

Comment: I don't. You can try to check at least if the port is open with telnet

Comment: If it is open, then the suggestion would be to read the SQL Server log, there might be something interested, however I do not know how do that from command line

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev: The port is open on localhost which I checked using netstat. But when I do telnet i get: "Connection closed by foreign host." So I think I need to enable TCP in SQL from command line.